# How to get user level from MySQL via PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I think I screwed here a lot. I'm sorry if it seems to easy for some of you. But I realy don't get it how should I get the parameter if the user is an admin or just an user.

My parameters are :
If typ is 1 = the user has admin privileges
If typ is 9 = the user has only normal privileges

From that privileges I would lovely to print some links... If you know what do I mean?

```
include ('./conf/connect.php');
        $typ = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM 'tz_members' WHERE 'typ'=($_GET'$typ')"); 
        if($typ == 1){
            print "POWER, ste prijavljen kot admin.";
            print etc...
            }
        if($typ == 9){
            print "Ste navaden uporabnik";
            print etc...

        }
```

Hopefully someone of you will be so kind to direct me in the right direction.
Cheers,
David

Comment: `typ` is the user input, why do you need to get it from the database? But your main problem is that you're not calling `mysql_fetch_XXX` to get the results of the query.

Comment: `'tz_members'` - why do you put single quotes around table name?

Comment: @Barmar: another "the main" problem is that the query is syntactically incorrect ))). And I don't even try to get what OP meant with `($_GET'$typ')`

Comment: @Roglič David-Rok: just a side note: learning is efficient when you do that iteratively. When you start doing something without knowing even basic things - it's just time wasting.

Comment: @zerkms thanks about that :) but i thought i would learn faster if i put something togther. If you know what i mean with that!

Comment: @Roglič David-Rok: from my experience (my own and the experience of people I've ever learnt) it never works

Answer (score 1):

Here's a correction of your code which should hopefully work:

```
<?php
include ('./conf/connect.php');

$var = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['typ']);

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `tz_members` WHERE `typ`='$var'") or die(mysql_error());
$data = mysql_fetch_array($query);
if($data['typ'] == 1){
     print "POWER, ste prijavljen kot admin.";
} elseif($data['typ'] == 9){
     print "Ste navaden uporabnik";
}
?>
```

The problem with doing it the way you were doing it is that:

1. You had no mysql injection prevention mysql_real_escape_string() helps with this, but you should use PDO.
2. Get variables are done via $_GET['variable_name']
3. You have to fetch the array or do a while loop to fetch multiple results when using mysql_query.
4. You should probably read up on PHP arrays so you can understand why $query['typ'] is used above if you haven't already.

Check out: http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/mysqlquery.php
Also: http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/mysqlselect.php

Comment: Thanks for the answer mate. I've tried it but nothing happens. Hah XD don't really get it what could be wrong.

Comment: Well let's break it down a bit, its possible that either A: I fat fingered something or B: your table doesn't quite match my code. Here lets break it apart and use or die(mysql_error())... I've edited my post above with the new code.

Comment: When your going to the URL in your browser are you typing something like this to test it?

http://mysite.com/test.php?typ=9

The $_GET['typ'] won't be able to magically come up with a number on its own.

Comment: Getting and error :)    Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /home/itps/public_html/index.php on line 306

Comment: Justin, I'm refreshing the index.php...because when the user is logged or logs in, then should the users is...the prints...

Comment: Try:

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `tz_members` WHERE typ='$var'") or die(mysql_error());

Comment: Waw, the error disappired but nothing happens or shows when i refresh.

Comment: After $data = mysql_fetch_array($query); put a new line with: var_dump($data); and see what it says.

Comment: This means there was no result for your query (IE: nothing in the database matched what you were looking for).

Comment: Ok thanks for sparing your time for me! I will come with something up. Be good :)

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems.

First, it should be `$_GET['typ']` instead of `$_GET'$typ'`.

Second, you will need to fetch a result from your query before using its values.

Third, consider using PDO because `mysql_.*` statements are depreciated and your method is vulnerable to SQL injection.

EDIT (from zerkms): Fourth, use "`" ticks around field names and single quotes around values.